# How to get Activities of each Account in Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am using this C# SDK to get data from Dynamics CRM 2011: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695803(v=crm.5).aspx

I need to read all the Accounts from it and to read the Activities associated with it (actually, only the last Closed and Open Activity).

To get the accounts I am using the following code:

```
var accounts = xrm.AccountSet
                .Select(acc => new
                {
                    name = acc.Name,
                    guid = acc.AccountId,
                    parent = acc.ParentAccountId,
                    number = acc.AccountNumber,
                    website = acc.WebSiteURL,
                });
```

This way has been suggested in this question: [Retrieve list of all accounts in CRM through C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082365/retrieve-list-of-all-accounts-in-crm-through-c?rq=1)

The problem is, I can't find a way to get the Activities. Is there a field associated with Activities? All I can find is a separate Activity Entity with it's own fields in the Dynamics CRM 2011 Solution.

Also I am new to C#.

EDIT: Thanks to Jordi, I now seem to be able to get a specific type of Activity using this:

```
public class AccountTask
        {
            public string account;
            public string task;
        }

var accountsAndTasks = (from t in xrm.CreateQuery<Task>() join a in xrm.CreateQuery<Account>() on t.RegardingObjectId.Id equals a.AccountId select new AccountTask {

               account = a.Name,
               task = t.OwnerId.Name.ToString()
}).ToList();
```

Now, is there a way to get all Activity types at once for each Account?

And, is it possible to only get the latest Open and Closed Activity for each Account?

Comment: Could you please describe the task more detailed? Do you need to fetch activities where an account specified in an activity "Regarding" field?

Comment: @Alex, I need to fetch all Activities to each existing Account. I guess the Account is specified in the Regarding Field, but I am not sure, that is my question, how to match Accounts and Activities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RegardingObjectId` field is one of the fields that relates an activity entity record to an account entity record.
You may fetch `activity` entity records like this:

```
var activityBaseList = serviceContext.CreateQuery<Activity>()
            .Where(x => x.RegardingObjectId.Id == accountId).ToList();
```

This is a base entity and it has **only basic information** about the activity. If you need more information about each activity record ( and in most cases you do need that) then you will have to make multiple queries with different activity types. Like this:

```
var emailActivityList = serviceContext.CreateQuery<Email>()
            .Where(x => x.RegardingObjectId.Id == accountId).ToList();
var taskActivityList = serviceContext.CreateQuery<Task>()
            .Where(x => x.RegardingObjectId.Id == accountId).ToList();
//and so on
```

I'd prefer using `QueryBase` requests because in that case you may combine queries into one `ExecuteMultipleRequest` call to `IOrganizationService` to improve the performance, but be aware of limitations: [info about ExecuteMultipleRequest limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#limitations).

**UPDATE**

I did not see your other question in the bottom. If you need to get only open activities you will need to add `x.StateCode == 0` to each query written above if you need only closed activities you will need to add `x.StateCode == 2`. For example, retrieve only open email activities:

```
var emailActivityList = serviceContext.CreateQuery<Email>()
            .Where(x => x.RegardingObjectId.Id == accountId && x.StateCode == 0).ToList();
```

[Here is the list](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531157.aspx) of all out of the box state codes and statuses for all entities.

If you need to retrieve let's say **only recent open activities** (you will define how recent you need by yourself) you make the following call:

```
var createdOnFilter = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1); //change it as you need it
var emailActivityList = serviceContext.CreateQuery<Email>()
            .Where(x => x.RegardingObjectId.Id == accountId && 
                        x.StateCode == 0 && 
                        x.CreatedOn >= createdOnFilter)
            .ToList();
```

This is a very basic code and there is plenty information about it on the WEB.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a join what you need.

There are different entities depending on the Activity type.

The following example is for Task activities, others would be similar.

```
//This will pull all the related tasks
var accountsAndTasks = (from t in xrm.CreateQuery<Task>()
            join a in xrm.CreateQuery<Account>() on t.RegardingObjectId.Id  equals a.AccountId
           select new AccountTask {
                account = a,
                task = t
           }).ToList();
```

If you need other examples of rather complex queries, please check [this](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy/blob/master/FakeXrmEasy.Tests/FakeContextTests/LinqTests/FakeContextTestLinqQueries.cs) example on Git.

Comment: Is there a way to get all of the activity types at once and not just Task?

Comment: Where does the AccountTask in your example come from? The SDK does not seem to recognize it.

Comment: This is the Error: "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'AccountTask' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I am new to C#, so will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: It's a custom class you can define anywhere in your code.