# In which library is `Contact` and other entities located?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm following [Retrieving list of Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409091/retrieving-list-of-entities) to retrieve contacts, but Visual Studio is not finding the reference to `Contact` and I can't find the documentation with it.

These are the libraries I have:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
```

Comment: Contact is an Entity which is part of CRM.

Comment: I see; never-mind then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the early-bound entities.

You need to generate them using the `crmsvcutil.exe` application included in the CRM 2013 SDK.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx

You can use also this tool to generate the classes:

https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/

There is also a youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkS3L1aHcUA